# flutter.io "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isMacOS' was called on null."

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been wanting to play around with flutter.io for a while now and got around to installing it today. I was following the Getting Started page on the flutter website but I have run into the following error message when running "flutter doctor"...is there something I am doing wrong? Or a workaround to get around this?

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 8a4b9d16bec30469)
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isMacOS' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isMacOS
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/dart:core/object_patch.dart:46)
#1      IOSDevices.supportsPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/devices.dart:34)
#2      DeviceManager._platformDiscoverers.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:85)
#3      WhereIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:439)
#4      DeviceManager.getAllConnectedDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:90)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      DeviceValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:560)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:71)
#7      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:128)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      _doctorText.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:237)
#9      AppContext._run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:76)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.runInZone.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:66)
#11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#13     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#14     AppContext.runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:65)
#15     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:237)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:212)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:167)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:94)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppContext._run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:76)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     AppContext.runInZone.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:66)
#21     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#22     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#23     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#24     AppContext.runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:65)
#25     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:48)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I noticed this issue on the github for flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16096 so I'm thinking this is a bug? Anything I can do to work around it so I can try flutter?

Thanks for the help!

Edit: I am running this on Windows 10 if that has anything to do with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ***flutter upgrade***  and then ***flutter doctor***

Comment: Thanks! Ended up getting v0.2.6 instead of the beta and that worked.